# How do I clear disk space on Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: disk-space, beta, catalina

diskutil shows

```
Container Total Space:     250.1 GB (250135076864 Bytes) (exactly 488545072 512-Byte-Units)
Container Free Space:      10.1 GB (10112528384 Bytes) (exactly 19751032 512-Byte-Units)
```

Finder says I have 48.56 GB available. Any suggestions for the 38 GB difference?

Catalina beta 4 won't download until I clear more space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is almost always TimeMachine snap shots.

For more info see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015

Answer (score 1):

You clear diskspace on Catalina same as you would on other Mac Systems. You need to move or remove some of the software on your disk drive. If you don't have another backup disk connected then maybe you can remove apps you bought from App Store and load them back after you get your system loaded.

You can run `df -h` from the command line and see what percent full your drive is. If you have about 50 GB free that is 20% of your 250 GB drive so your drive should be only 80%.

You can set up iCloud by going to System Preferences and selecting iCloud. See image below.

[image]

Be sure to check the box to the left of iCloud Drive and also click on the option button. The option button opens a panel like the one below. Be sure click on the checkbox in the red rectangle.

[image]

After doing this wait about 30 minutes and check how much free space you have.

Comment: This did not answer the question about the difference between finder free space and terminal free space.

Comment: I suggested he use the unix command df to get an accurate value.

Comment: df-h was helpful.